# Where does secondary image in (node.js) Windows 8 toast notification come from?

Tags: node.js, windows-8, toast, node-notifier

I'm using `node-notifier` ([link](https://github.com/mikaelbr/node-notifier)) in `node.js` to show a toast notification in Windows 8. I have it working and I'm able to adjust the title, text, and main image in the notification just fine. However, in a Windows 8 toast notifications, there is a secondary (smaller) image. See below:

[image: Windows 8 toast notification]

So, `node-notifier` uses [toaster](https://github.com/nels-o/toaster), which in turn uses [ToastNotificationManager](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.notifications.toastnotificationmanager.aspx). But, I cannot find any reference anywhere to this secondary image. I've looked [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh761494.aspx#image-and-text_templates) and [here](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/trycatchfinally/archive/2013/03/07/windows-store-app-toast-notification-templates-javascript-c-push-notifications.aspx) on Microsoft's site.

This secondary image also shows in other notifications I receive from applications like Outlook, Slack, etc.

Where is this secondary image coming from? Is the documentation just out of date? Can Toaster be modified to access this secondary image?

Comment: It looks to me like it might be the icon of the program that showed the toast?

Comment: @JoeClay yeah, could be. I was hoping there was a way to hide it and/or change it since it's not picking up the application icon (or maybe it needs a certain type of icon/size/whatever to work). Regardless, I can't find any reference to it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The secondary image is the icon for the shortcut in the Start Menu folder for the program registered to raise a toast. To change it, you'll need to modify the icon on the shortcut.

For a desktop application to use the [`ToastNotificationManager`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.notifications.toastnotificationmanager.aspx) class, it is required to have a shortcut in the start menu, and an AppUserModelId associated with that shortcut. At  [`ToastNotificationManager`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.notifications.toastnotificationmanager.aspx) creation time, the caller passes in the same AppUserModelId, which ties back to the associated icon for the shortcut. More about registering desktop applications to raise toasts this can be found on [this MSDN documentation page](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/hh802762(v=vs.85).aspx).

Looking at the [toaster code here](https://github.com/nels-o/toaster/blob/master/toast/Program.cs), it is installing the shortcut to a file called toast.lnk in the Start Menu:

```
String shortcutPath = 
    Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.ApplicationData) +
    "\\Microsoft\\Windows\\Start Menu\\Programs\\toast.lnk";
```

And, it is creating the shortcut targeting the initial calling process:

```
String exePath = Process.GetCurrentProcess().MainModule.FileName;
```

Updating the icon in the shortcut manually should verify that you can change what is shown locally, but an update to toaster to set the icon location is likely required (to support multiple callers with different shortcuts, or by having it call [`IShellLink::SetIconLocation`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb761047(v=vs.85).aspx)).

Comment: After replacing the icon on the `lnk` file at the specified path, the icon updated in the toast notification. And I see how I could modify Toaster to make this more flexible. Thanks!